# trying to get value from one component in a module to app.component.ts using viewChild()

Tags: angular, angular-components

I am trying to get the property(bookmarkedCount) value present in a component of a module to app component using view child in app.component.ts.But I am getting an error at reading the property value in app component is undefined. Why is it so?

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'bookmarkedCount' of undefined
>       at AppComponent.push../src/app/app.component.ts.AppComponent.ngAfterViewInit (app.component.ts:36)

app.component.ts

```
@ViewChild(ContainerComponent) private containerComponent:ContainerComponent;

ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.count = this.containerComponent.bookmarkedCount;  //getting error here reading the value of bookmarkedCount
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this -

```
export class AppComponent  {
    bookmarkedCount: any;
    constructor(private containerComponentComponent: ContainerComponentComponent){
        this.bookmarkedCount = this.containerComponentComponent.bookmarkedCount;
   }
}
```

see [details here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x81fnz)

Comment: @sonu kumar, please let me know it it helped.

Comment: here i am initiating the value of bookmarkedCount on ngOninit() using a service.So,when fetching the value of bookmarkedCount in app component the value still remains undefined .If i am hardcoding the value like you did then it is getiing the value but this is not the case in my problem.                                          ---> ngOnInit() {
    this.jobService.viewBookmarks().subscribe(res => {
      this.bookmarkedCount = res.length;
    });
//    this.dataService.changeCount(this.bookmarkedCount);
  }

Comment: Can you please provide a stackblitz link?

Comment: @Harnur Rashid This is the actual problem i am talking about                              
    .-->https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nal1cc

Answer (score 0):

I think here you doing it in a right way,

but sometimes the **`ngAfterViewInit()`** is called before the child gets rendered. we generally use **`ngOnInit()`** for this kind of bindings.

So try like this ..

```
@ViewChild(ContainerComponent) private containerComponent:ContainerComponent;

ngOnInit() {
    this.count = this.containerComponent.bookmarkedCount;  
}
```

I hope this will solve your issue :)

Comment: I tried doing this it doesn't works.Still errror remains same.

Comment: create a stackblitz and reproduce the issue there, that way it is easier to solve your issue.. cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

Didn't found any easier alternative solution.So atlast i created a shared service to get the value of bookmarkedCount in app component and updated it on changes in the service.Here i am calling the changeCount method whenever add/delete bookmark is clicked

```
 //for bookmark count 
  private count:number;

  private messageSource = new BehaviorSubject(this.count);
  currentCount = this.messageSource.asObservable();

  changeCount(count: number) {
    if(count!=undefined)
    this.messageSource.next(count);
  }
```

in app.component.ts ->

```
  updateCount(){
    this.dataService.currentCount.subscribe(res => {
      this.count = res;
    });
    return true;
  }
```